# Why I can't see the debug output when I run a test in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am very new in C# and Visual Studio (I came from Java) and I have the following doubts about how debug work in Visual Studio.

So I have this unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetVulnerability()
    {
        DataModel.VulnerabilityManager manager = new DataModel.VulnerabilityManager("DefaultConnection");

        try
        {
            manager.openConnection();


            List<DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall> risultato;

            DataModel.Vulnerability.SearchVuln model = new DataModel.Vulnerability.SearchVuln();
            model.PageSize = 20;
            /*model.Filter.CVE = "CVE-2013-2902(Candidate)";*/

            int numeroRecordsTotali;

            risultato = manager.getList(model, out numeroRecordsTotali);

            foreach (DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall v in risultato ){
                Debug.WriteLine("MY CVE: " + v.CVE + "**");
            }

        }
        finally
        {

            manager.closeConnection();
        }
```

So, into the **foreach** I print the test output by the line

```
Debug.WriteLine("MY CVE: " + v.CVE + "**")
```

The thing that I can't understand is that when I go to execute the test clicking on **Run selected test** voice I can't see the test output that have to be written by my previous line but I can see it if I click on the **Debug selected test** voice.

Why? What can I do to show the desidered output (and not only if the test is passed) in Visual Studio debug?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has to do with the fact that [Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is tagged with `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`.

For all intents and purposes, you may think of it being equivalent to this:

```
public void WriteLine(string message)
{
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine(message);
#endif
}
```

Now you probably already guessed it, but your tests don't run in debug mode.

**Solution**

Use the `Trace` class instead of the `Debug` class.

```
foreach ( DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall v in risultato )
{
    Trace.WriteLine("MY CVE: " + v.CVE + "**");
}
```